# Unitary Transformation Taking a 4$\pi$ Periodic Wave Function to 2$\pi$ Periodic Wave Function

Tags: wavefunction, unitarity, parity, majorana-fermions, josephson-junction

I am reading the following [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/14/3/035019), which discusses Majorana fermions in Josephson junction arrays. Initially, the paper starts with a model such that the wavefunctions are $4\pi$ periodic. These satisfy the following relationship (see equation 5 of the paper too):

$$
\Psi(\phi + 2\pi) = (-1)^{(1 - \hat{P})/2} \Psi(\phi)
$$

I understand why these wavefunctions are $4\pi$.

Now, equation A.1.  of the paper discusses what happens when one performs the unitary transformation on the Hamiltonian:

$$
H' = \Omega^\dagger H \Omega \text{ where } \Omega = \exp[i(1 - \hat{P}) \phi_i/4] \text{ and } \Psi'(\phi) = \Omega^\dagger \Psi(\phi)
$$

The claim is that the transformed wavefunction is $2\pi$ periodic. I do not see why:

$$
\Psi'(\phi + 2\pi) = \Omega^\dagger \Psi(\phi + 2\pi) = \Omega^\dagger(-1)^{(1 - \hat{P})/2} \Psi(\phi)
$$

How is the last term equal to $\Psi'(\phi)$?

Comment: Note that $\Omega$ also depends on $\phi$. So when shifting $\phi$ by $2\pi$, $\Omega\rightarrow \Omega e^{i\pi(1-P)/2}=\Omega (-1)^{(1-P)/2}$, which cancels the additional $(-1)^{(1-P)/2}$ factor and makes $\Psi'$ $2\pi$ periodic.

Comment: @MengCheng Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note (I'm assuming there are no operator ordering issues)
\begin{eqnarray}
\Omega(\phi+2\pi) &=& \Omega(\phi) e^{i(1-\hat{P})\pi/2} = \Omega(\phi)\left(e^{i\pi}\right)^{(1-\hat{P})/2} = \Omega^\dagger(\phi) (-1)^{(1-\hat{P})/2} \\
\Omega^\dagger(\phi+2\pi) &=& \Omega(\phi) \left((-1)^{(1-\hat{P})/2}\right)^\dagger
\end{eqnarray}
So
\begin{eqnarray}
\Psi'(\phi+2\pi) &=& \Omega^\dagger(\phi+2\pi) \Psi(\phi+2\pi) \\
&=& \left[\Omega^\dagger(\phi) \left((-1)^{(1-\hat{P})/2}\right)^\dagger\right]\left[(-1)^{(1-\hat{P})/2} \Psi(\phi)\right] \\
&=& \left|(-1)^{(1-\hat{P})/2}\right|^2 \Omega^\dagger(\phi) \Psi(\phi) \\
&=& \Psi'(\phi)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks again for your answer